# Freebase get a list of topics with filter

Tags: freebase

Is it possible to get Freebase's topics with some filter applied?

Freebase contains about 28 millions topics now.

I want to get all topics name except, for example, Records names( ~ 7 millions topics).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You can do this through the API easily, but for the number of topics that you want, you are better off using the data dumps.

Grab this 1.4 GB file: http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/latest/freebase-simple-topic-dump.tsv.bz2

and use the command

```
bzegrep -v $'/music/recording[\t,]' freebase-simple-topic-dump.tsv.bz2 | cut -f 2 > names.txt
```

In a few minutes you'll have your 21 million names.

Comment: Is this file still available anywhere? It seems like this and other download.freebase.com links have gone cold. Thanks!

Comment: The simple topic dump is no longer being generated.  The documentation for the current dump is here: https://developers.google.com/freebase/data It's 20+ GB and has the name and type on separate lines, so it's a little more involved to do simple tasks like this question was about.